# Google Earth Engine: change multiple labels in legend for time series by region graph

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, graph

I am producing a time series graph comparing the mean NDVI in two different types of regions. Both types exist out of multiple polygons (MultiPolygons). However, I keep failing to name these two regions in my legend of my time series graph. Adding it as a 7th argument in ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion only works if I have one region since it only accept one string and not a list of strings. How can I change labels in the legend of a graph of series (as indicated .setSeriesNames did not work for me either).

```
// Create a time series chart.
var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([Small_Avocado_Farms,Large_Avocado_Companies]) // featurecollection from two multipolygons
var tempTimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    all_images_ndvi, regions, ee.Reducer.mean(),'NDVI',30)
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setSeriesNames(['Small','Large'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'NDVI of small- vs. large-scale avocado farms ',
          vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
          pointSize: 4,
          legend: {position: 'top'}
          })

print(tempTimeSeries)
```

[image: Output Graph]

The following answers did not work for me:
[Change the label of the ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280029/change-the-label-of-the-ui-chart-image-seriesbyregion-in-google-earth-engine)

Comment: The code snippet does not include enough information so that others can reproduce the issue and help you. Please add code that defines all variables used (Small_Avocado_Farms, Large_Avocado_Companies, all_images_ndvi) by loading publicly accessible datasets and/or constructing them in the script.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the order of the two lines:
(`SeriesNames` must be set before `ChartType`)

```
.setSeriesNames(['Small','Large'])        
.setChartType('ScatterChart')
```