# Adding Labels to ui.Chart.seriesByRegion with two lines in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series

I would like to change the labels for a seriesByRegion chart in GEE.

```
var vegIndices = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
                        .filter(ee.Filter.date('2015-01-01', '2020-12-31'))
                        .select(['NDVI']);

var NDVIchart = 
    ui.Chart.image
        .seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection: vegIndices,
          band: 'NDVI',
          // these are two geometries
          regions: [gota, anwr],
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 30,
          //seriesProperty: 'label',
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average NDVI Value by Date',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          VAxis: {
            title: 'NDVI (x1e4)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['f0af07','0f8755','76b349'],
        });
```

I was able to get two lines to show by commenting out the seriesProperty argument, but I can't get the labels to change. I would like the labels to read 'GOTA' and 'ANWR'.

These answers did not work for me:
[Google Earth Engine: change multiple labels in legend for time series by region graph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346136/google-earth-engine-change-multiple-labels-in-legend-for-time-series-by-region)
[Change the label of the ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280029/change-the-label-of-the-ui-chart-image-seriesbyregion-in-google-earth-engine)

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
.seriesByRegion({}).setSeriesNames(['GOTA', 'ANWR'])
```

after your chart functions